# PHPExcel error when opening created File in EXCEL

Tags: php, phpexcel

I create with a php-script which uses the PHPExcel Library an simple .xlsx file. But when I want to open it in MS Excel 2010 on Win7, I get an error message that file format is wrong or the file is damaged. Tried several possible solutions from the internet but nothing worked for me.

public function createControllingFile($suffix){
        $this->PHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

```
    $year = date('y');

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');


    $this->objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->PHPExcel, 'excel5');


    $this->objWriter->save('tmp/controlling_'.$year.'_'.$suffix.'.xlsx');

    $_SESSION['counter'] = 0;

    exit();
}
```

Hope you can help me, the session thing is to count up something

Comment: You are not actually sending any data to the browser...

Comment: As @Jon noticed, you are preparing the data, but you never `echo` it out. So your document is blank.

Comment: @Dainis - not echo, save to php://output

Comment: Note that an .xlsx (OfficeOpenXML) file is written by the Excel2007 Writer, the Excel5 Writer is used to create .xls (BIFF8) files... and the Writer names are case-sensitive

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->objWriter->save('tmp/controlling_'.$year.'_'.$suffix.'.xlsx');
```

saves to a file on your servers filesystem, and nothing is sent to the client browser.

If you want to send to the client's browser, change that line to:

```
$this->objWriter->save('php://output');
```

just like in `01simple-download-xlsx.php` in the /Tests or /Examples directory